custom google login button in React
I am developing using React.
While creating a personal project, I implemented a login pop-up, but I didn't like Google's default button, so '< /a>' I decided to use this tag, but onclick doesn't work, so I want to give the login attribute to this tag and have the Google login window pop up when clicked. What should I do??? The basic Google oAuth setup is now complete. .
index.html
<a href="#" class="social" onclick="GoogleLoginButton"><i class="fa fa-google"></i>< /a>
.
.
.
<script src="../src/GoogleLoginButton.js"></script>

GoogleLoginButton.js
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google'
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google'

function GoogleLoginButton() {

    const clientId = "…";
    
    return (
        <>
            <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={clientId}>
                <GoogleLogin
                    onSuccess={(res) => {
                        console.log(res);
                    }}
                    onFailure={(err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    }}
                    type='icon'
                    size='medium'
                />
            </GoogleOAuthProvider>
        </>
    )
}

export default GoogleLoginButton;


hide the clientId, it is supposed to be secret.

@Ghazi Could you tell me in detail?
